# Resize the textarea to fit the page vertically

Tags: html

I am try to resize a textarea (form which will be replaced by CKEditor to be precise) to fit the whole page, this is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
        <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center" style="font-family:Consolas;">AIO HTML WYSIWYG Editor</h1>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="50" cols="80">

            </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is how it currently looks like: 
[image: Screenshot of the page in firefox]
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Which part of your code attempts the resizing? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it depends on which version you are using. Have you had a look at http://ckeditor.com/addon/maximize ?

Also, you could try javascript to call the built in maximize feature:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady',
      function( evt )
      {
         var editor = evt.editor;
         editor.execCommand('maximize');
      });
};
</script>
```

(note: this code is posted all over the web, I copied this particular snippet from experts exchange)

Answer (score 0):

JS :

```
screen.width;
screen.height;
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("someIDofElement").style.width=screen.width-0+'px'; /* -0 not need but if you need you can do -100 or +100 if need*/
    document.getElementById("someIDofElement").style.height=screen.height-0+'px';
```

Comment: I don't know how to use them, please post the code.